# Handle CSS with dynamic ids

Tags: html, css

My html page is something like...

```
<a href="#" id="play_1">play1</a>
<a href="#" id="play_2">play2</a>
<a href="#" id="play_1">play3</a>
<a href="#" id="play_2">play4</a>
<a href="#" id="file_1">file1</a>
<a href="#" id="file_2">file2</a>
```

I want to define CSS common for play_"#" and file_"#". How can i define CSS?

Comment: Did you forget about the `class` attribute? :)

Comment: Ids have to be unique, meaning that there should only be one `id="play_1"` in the entire document. That's why it's an ID. Like your ID identifies you and only you, so this should be the same. Use classes instead, they can be used over and over until.. Well, however much you want really..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the tags

```
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_1">play1</a>
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_2">play2</a>
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_1">play3</a> <!-- double ID -->
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_2">play4</a> <!-- double ID -->
<a href="#" class="file" id="file_1">file1</a>
<a href="#" class="file" id="file_2">file2</a>
```

Because you have double id's, either remove the ID's at all or make them unique

```
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_1">play1</a>
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_2">play2</a>
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_3">play3</a> 
<a href="#" class="play" id="play_4">play4</a>
<a href="#" class="file" id="file_1">file1</a>
<a href="#" class="file" id="file_2">file2</a>
```

In css use

```
.play {
  /* add your common play styles here */
}
.file {
  /* add your common file styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each link and target that instead.

E.g.

```
<a href="#" id="play_1" class="play">play1</a>
<a href="#" id="play_2" class="play">play2</a>
<a href="#" id="play_1" class="play">play3</a>
<a href="#" id="play_2" class="play">play4</a>
<a href="#" id="file_1>file1</a>
<a href="#" id="file_2">file2</a>
```

Then your css will look like:

```
.play {
   //Style here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish this task, is to use css attribute selectors. In this case it would be:

```
a[id^="play_"] {
  /* your declarations */
}
```

and

```
a[id^="file_"] {
  /* your declarations */
}
```

These attribute selectors simply select elements that have attribute "id", that starts with the specified value, in this case it's "file_" or "play_".
Also you should get rid of duplicate id's. Either way this will work and latest browser versions probably will ignore your duplicate id's and render page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is slightly Syntax Mistake where you write `id="Play_1"`

Pleas follow Programming pattern use classes where you can define element attributes and use that class to all elements where you want that effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.play_1 {
background-color : green;
}
.play_2 {
background-color : red;
}
</style>
<body>
<a href="#" class="play_1">play1</a>
<a href="#" class="play_2">play2</a>

<a href="#" class="play_1">play3</a>
<a href="#" class="play_2">play4</a>

<a href="#" class="play_1">file1</a>
<a href="#" class="play_2">file2</a>
</body>
</html>
```